# How do you add two independent master's degrees to your name?

Tags: masters, europe, degree, second-degree

Assuming you add one master's degree (*Master of Science*) like that:

```
FirstName LastName, M.Sc.
```

What is a proper way to add two independent<sup>1</sup> master's degrees (both *Master of Science*)? Do you just add them both to the end?

```
FirstName LastName, M.Sc., M.Sc.
```

<sup>1</sup> independent: Different universities, different fields, 2x 120 ECTS = 240 ECTS in total. Not the result of a [double degree program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_degree).

---

**Just to be clear**, I am not looking for recommendations, *if* or *when* I should decorate my name with academic degrees. I do not even plan to do it on a regular basis. Even in my country, you don't do it very often. But if there is this one single time in my whole life where I should do it, then I want to do it right. That's all I am asking for: Are there rules or good/best practices on how to do it with two M.Sc. degrees.

Example situation: If you get mentioned on someone else's thesis as an examiner or as a supervisor the names will be decorated with degrees. A german doctor with three doctoral degress can either be `Dr. Dr. Dr. FirstName LastName` or `Dr. mult. FirstName LastName`. This example shows two possible rules:

1. You can stack titles/degrees. Just add as much as you have. That's from where I derived `FirstName LastName, M.Sc., M.Sc.`.
2. You can condense - at least multiple doctoral - degrees by adding `mult.` to the mention of one single title/degree. I have never seen this in combination with other degrees.

Comment: This might be countty specific. Have you searched the Internet for it? Iam kinda surprised if there exist no legal requirements in your country.

Comment: @user111388, I doubt that many countries have legal requirements for academic titles.

Comment: @Buffy: That's to me strange. Isn't there fear of misrepresentation if anyone can mention their titles in any way? Do you know if at least the fact the one can not use "any title they feel like" is legally required in many countries?

Comment: @user111388 I found some discussions on the internet, but most of them tend to become discussions about _if_ you should add academic degrees to your name and not how to do it.

Comment: @user111388, I think that if there is no intent to defraud, then it is benign. Medical degrees may be a bit different. But few (in the US) would object if I suddenly start calling myself Buffy, MS of the Universe. A few laughs, perhaps. I think Germany is quite strict about titles along with other countries in the German academic tradition. But it is fraud that is a crime, not the listing of titles.

Comment: @user111388 in my country, only the doctorate is legally protected among academic title. Anybody can choose to self-style themselves as a professor, for example. It's probably bad for your reputation, but you are not legally forbidden from doing so. Only the doctorate is actually illegal to claim if you don't have one.

Comment: @Wetenschaap: Wow, that sounds pretty weird to my ears! I wonder if you confer yourself the professor (or, as Buffy, the MS of the universe title) title, move to my country, use the title because you earned it in your country and get the social privileges associated to it.

Comment: I would suggest that you specify if you are interested in the German/Austrian practice or in the rest-of-the-world practice, since they are quite different. Please add also a country tag if relevant.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I added the *europe* tag as I am referring to the [european master's degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%27s_degree_in_Europe). But I really hope that it does not matter much. I am hoping for an *international* consensus.

Comment: @Thomas I don't think there is an international consensus at all.

Comment: @Wetenschaap the MSc, BA, MA, BSc, drs., ir., and mr. titles are also protected under Dutch law.

Comment: @mmeent in 2008, minister Plasterk explicitly mentioned that he would not lawfully protect bachelor and master titles. See, for instance, here: https://www.scienceguide.nl/2008/02/nederland-wil-titels-niet-beschermen/ . If you have a more recent source that shows that things have changed in the mean time (which is very well possible! Lots can change in 13 years), I would be happy to learn this.

Comment: @Wetenschaap See: https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/stb-2017-390.html (i.e. this was was changed only a couple of years ago.)

Comment: Page 20 (by the number printed at the bottom of the page) or page 22 (by the PDF file page count) of the [Oxford University Style Guide](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/University%20of%20Oxford%20Style%20Guide%20%28updated%20Hilary%20term%202016%29.pdf) gives an example arrangement of postnominal letters for someone who has three M.A.s (among many other degrees), but I don't think it has any currency outside Oxford.

Comment: In Germany I have often seen multiple titles in death notices in the newspaper, but I have never paid attention to the particulars of formatting. It's certainly not uncommon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unless you are in a place that regulates academic titles, you can do pretty much as you please. But you could qualify each with the specific field or university if you feel the need to list both.

> FirstName LastName, M.Sc.(Basket Weaving), M.Sc.(Basket Burning)

Distinguishing by university, rather than field will probably confuse people, thinking you have two masters in the same field. Qualifying with both is probably too unwieldy.

Answer (score 6):

**You don't.** Even in academic circles, writing "John Smith, MS, MS" just looks silly and pompous. Instead, simply write "John Smith, MS." In the same way, you would not ask people to call you "doctor doctor" if you had two PhDs, nor would you write "MS, BS, BA" if you did a dual degree in college but subsequently got a master's.

You may want "credit" for your two different degrees, but this is not the purpose of the initials. Rather, you can list both degrees separately on your resume, or describe yourself in a bio as having "two master's degrees."

Granted, this answer is from a US perspective; it is possible that this would look less silly to members of other cultures.

Comment: I come from a culture where it would be the normal thing to state both titles. However, in academic circles, you would most likely (unless in social/law science) mention neither title. Therefore, I am confused about the "even in academic cicles"at the start of the answer- is it really the case that in the US, you use titles more in academia than in industry/private life?

Comment: By "academic circles," I meant only that we know what these letters mean, and value them. But no, post-nominals are rarely used in daily life -- a formal e-mail signature block is the only example that comes to mind.

Comment: @user111388 sounds a lot like Austria.

Comment: I never bothered with "MS" even when I was teaching; I couldn't have been teaching without that master's.  I didn't use a post-nominal degree until I earned the Ph.D. and then only in the academic setting or when consulting.

Answer (score 2):

There are some indications that one could use `MMSc` to designate a double 'master of science'-degre.

[Here](https://forschung.boku.ac.at/fis/suchen.person_uebersicht?sprache_in=en&menue_id_in=101&id_in=153281) is an example of a profile who calls himself `Dr. ... MMSc`.

As for the rationale behind that, I may cite this Wikipedia section on representing plurals in acronyms:

> In some languages, the convention of doubling the letters in the acronym is used to indicate plural words: for example, the Spanish *EE.UU.*, for *Estados Unidos* ('United States'). This old convention is still followed for a limited number of English abbreviations, such as *SS.* for "Saints", *pp.* for the Latin plural of "pages", *paginae*, or *MSS* for "manuscripts".

This approach of pluralizing acronyms is quite common with academic titles in German, e.g. `DDr.` for "Doktor Doktor", or `MMag.` for "Magister Magister". Thus, `MMSc` would serve as an analogy.

Interestingly, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MMSC does state that the acronym may refer to "Double Master of Science, an academic degree". And if you google around, you find some examples of such usages.